# Internal Network Default Gateway

Tags: hyper-v

Here is my Hyper-V network topology:

(VM) DomainController1 - 10.0.0.1
(VM) Server1 - 10.0.0.2
(VM) Server2 - 10.0.0.3

In Hyper-V, I have created a virtual switch that is an internal network switch.  I have the above static IPs set for the three servers.

Since this is an internal network, what should I be using as the Default Gateway for the network settings on these 3 servers?  I can't seem to ping Server1 to Server2, and I'm guessing that is the disconnect.

Comment: If this is an internal network then there is no need for a default gateway for the servers to speak to each other and they reside on the same switch. The default gateway is used if the traffic is intended for an external network and not an internal one as is your case. Are you allowing ICMP traffic through your Windows Firewalls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The default gateway has nothing to do with hosts on the same subnet, it comes only into play when you have packets with a destination address *outside* that subnet. You do need to make sure that all VMs have the same netmask, though. Other things to check:

- network adapter connection status (OS and VM configuration)
- Windows Firewall
- routing table